# With Rails REST helpers, how do you tell the difference between create and index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I noticed when looking up Rails REST helpers that `create` and `index` share a common helper (using subject as variable) `subjects_path`. How can you tell the difference say if you wanted to use a `link_to` of where it would redirect the request, to `index` or `create`?  And is there a point of them needing to share the same URL and URL helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create` uses the `POST` HTTP protocol method while `index` uses `GET`.

So, for your `link_to` example: `link_to 'create', subjects_path, method: :post` (default is `GET`)